# PDF view not presenting

Tags: swift, xcode, pdf, pdfkit, swift5

I'm downloading a PDF from a url and then displaying it using PDFKit in Swift5. However, when I tap my viewCell it is not presenting the PDF and potentially not downloading the PDF. How can I verify this?

I have two files, PlanogramViewController and ShowPDFViewController.

```
var pdfURL: URL!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let plano = self.data[indexPath.row] as? Planogram {
            guard let url = URL(string: Plano.pdfUrl) else { return }

            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

            let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
            downloadTask.resume()

            let pdfViewController = ShowPDFViewController()
            pdfViewController.pdfURL = self.pdfURL
            present(pdfViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    }

extension PlanogramViewController:  URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("downloadLocation:", location)
        // create destination URL with the original pdf name
        guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        // delete original copy
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        // copy from temp to Document
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
            self.pdfURL = destinationURL
        } catch let error {
            print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm not getting any download verification from my extension. It should be printing my initial download location and then moving it to the cache. If it encounters an error it should also print an error, but I'm getting nothing in the console. As if nothing is downloading.

Then here is the pdfViewController it's supposed to present once it has the PDF downloaded:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit


class ShowPDFViewController: UIViewController {

    var pdfView = PDFView()
    var pdfURL: URL!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(pdfView)

        if let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        pdfView.frame = view.frame
    }
}
```

The current behavior is it just highlights the cell I tapped. Nothing in the console and nothing presented on the display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform to the **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSourceDelegate** protocols in the view controller that has the tableView.

and add

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

in the viewDidLoad()

Then, implement the required methods, and add optional methods to further customize  your tableView.

Comment: I have already conformed in my code (I just didn't include the class declaration in the post, my bad)